# HTTPS Redirect Breaks Rewrite Rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I am having a little trouble trying to understand what exactly is going on with my redirects.

This works good:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# redirect to http subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.m\.pets4you\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.pets4you.com/$1 [L,R=301]


##################################
RewriteRule ^dogs/(.*).htm?$ breeds.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*).htm?$ breeds.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm?$ pets4you.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But this....

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# redirect to http subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.m\.pets4you\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://m.pets4you.com/$1 [L,R=301]

##################################
RewriteRule ^dogs/(.*).htm?$ breeds.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*).htm?$ breeds.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm?$ pets4you.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Redirects to:
https://m.pets4you.com/pets4you.php?page=https://m.pets4you.com/dogs/breedname.htm

Any ideas why?
It is ignoring the first two rules and going directly to the last rule.

I do know of a workaround, but entails rewriting the php code to do it worpdress style, and change .htaccess.

The site is old and outdated and will be replaced with an actual wordpress site. But for now I am being asked to do this to this site. And a first time experiencing this kind of issue.

I personally despise .htaccess as it is not my best area. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As always, the moment I ask a question I figure it out. A matter of some hardcoded URL's without https causing issues. Forgot to check the main index page. As I usually have the URL as a PHP variable.